# Using 5 V instead of a pull-up resistor?

Tags: resistors, pullup

I was researching pull-up resistors. One reason to use them is to give a solid high to our input pin, but I can't figure out why I should use a resistor in this setup.  What if we connect 5 V without the resistor? What is the contribution of the resistor?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHMDU2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Pullups are sometimes used when multiple outputs are connected together. Any one or more of the outputs can either drive low or let the pullup do its job. A direct connection to 5 V would not work the same way in such a situation. Any output that tried to drive the 5V rail low would probably just burn up.

Comment: Please research further.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In one word : short-circuits

What happens to your 5v voltage source when you close your switch? On your schematics we see that the 5V will be connected to GND **without limiting the current**.

Using the lumped element model, this is not possible because you will impose 5V and 0V at the same time to the same net. Which is impossible...

But as you may have tried, you can do this in the real world and nothing fancy will happens, no *infinite current* or *universe singularity* will happen.

This is because in the real world, wires are not perfect conductors, and power supplies are not perfect voltage sources.

If I translate your real world circuit into a lumped element model schematics I end up with :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuGSgP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To model the non-perfect behavior of the voltage source, a resistor in series is added to the model. We call it *internal resistance*. And it's usually small. That way our model behave the same way the real world does when you short a real voltage source such as a battery. I have put 1 Ohm for the purpose of my demonstration.

Here when you close the switch, a current of 5A will flow through it.

5V in a 1 Ohm resistor : I = U/R -> 5A
That is huge, will deplete your battery quickly, heat up you power supply,  may destroy your power regulator chip, or do plenty of other uncool things.

But, the most important point it that the 5V output of your real world volage source, (the dotted box) is no longer 5V but 0V !

All the things that are connected to that 5V supply rail won't be powered anymore. Microcontrollers will reboot for instance.

A solution would be to find a way to put Vin to GND **without** putting the whole 5V rail to its knee. And here comes the pull up resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWCoaT.png)</sup>

Here you can see that the 5V power supply can stay at 5V because R1, has **limited the current**. The current drawn from the 5V voltage source is now :

I = U/R = 5V / 10000 Ohm = 0.5mA.

That 0.5mA will also flow through the Rser of the real world voltage supply and that will result to a voltage drop of : 0.5mV

Our real world 5V voltage source will now output : 4.9995....
Well, that's fine. And that voltage source can continue to power other parts of the circuit and won't be damaged when you close your switch.

Answer (score 5):

Your example shows a pull-up on a digital input with a switch to ground.

If you close that switch, it will short the 5V supply to ground.  That will cause your circuit to malfunction. It might destroy the switch, it might destroy the power supply, it might destroy the circuit board - and it might just all go back to work when you open the switch.

The resistor allows the switch to pull the input to ground without causing a short circuit.

Answer (score 1):

To use a pull-up resistor, the input being driven must draw an acceptably small-enough current.

Consider when driving a logic gate input...

Almost all general logic families introduced since about 1986 have a very small input current, in the order of +/- 10 uA max. This means when the input is driven HIGH, it will draw 10 uA max. and when driven LOW, it will leak out up to 10 uA max. into the driver.

A pull-up resistor must supply the 10 uA max. without creating too large a voltage drop across itself, so the voltage it delivers to the input is still a good logic HIGH.

Similarly, a pull-down resistor must sink this 10 uA max. without creating too large a voltage drop across itself, so the voltage it delivers to the input is a good logic LOW.

In this circuit and with SW1 open, a 10 uA input current would drop (47000 x 0.00001) = 0.47 V across R1. So Vi will be (3.3 - 0.47) = 2.83 V, comfortably above the gate's (say) 2 V min. voltage for a logic HIGH.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx6cx1m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, when driving a higher-current load, such as a device input that draws 50 mA input current max. and needs pulling up to at least 2.5 V, the above circuit's pull-up resistor would have to be (0.8/0.05) = 16 ohms.

Then when SW1 is switched on, R1 would draw (3.3/16) = 206 mA and dissipate (3.3 x 0.206) = 0.68 W within itself. That's normally an unacceptable waste of power and heat rise.

There are better ways of driving the same input, such as from a buffer driver that has a very small input current draw and strong push-pull output drive. Just a pull-up resistor would not normally be used.